# Reference a custom figure type in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

If I try to reference a custom figure class

```py
class MyFigure(
    sphinx.util.docutils.SphinxDirective, 
    docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images.Figure
):
    pass

def setup(app):
    app.add_role('fig', MyFigure)
```

Then use it like

```
.. fig:: foo.png
    :name: myfig


Look at :ref:`myfig`.
```

Any reference will fail with

```
WARNING: undefined label: myfig
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docutils.parsers.rst.directives.images.Figure` is not the right class to customize because it doesn't handle the `name` attribute. Use Sphinx's patched version, `sphinx.directives.patches.Figure`, instead.